# SQL placeholders

Tags: sql, sql-server

So it seems that in transact SQL i can use as a placeholder %d in my RAISEERROR() just like C#... But what does really the "%d" D stand for? and are there any other similar placeholders like this?

Comment: Please see the documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms178592.aspx

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx. About half way down

Comment: so basically this thing Type specification Represents
d or i Signed integer
o Unsigned octal
s String
u Unsigned integer
x or X Unsigned hexadecimal
?

Comment: any idea what is an Unsigned octal ? and isn't there a placeholder that doesn't care if it's a char or an int or whatever? like c#?

Comment: This is just a lazy post. Little to no research done. That you ever coded before? C, C+? How does the op not know that RAISERROR enables the user to mimic the PRINT command in C++ or the COUT command in C#? Do research instead of wasting our time and yours.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the MSDN documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms178592.aspx

> Typically, successive arguments replace successive conversion specifications; the first argument replaces the first conversion specification, the second argument replaces the second conversion specification, and so on. For example, in the following RAISERROR statement, the first argument of N'number' replaces the first conversion specification of %s; and the second argument of 5 replaces the second conversion specification of %d.

```
 RAISERROR (N'This is message %s %d.', -- Message text.  
       10, -- Severity,  
       1, -- State,  
       N'number', -- First argument.  
       5); -- Second argument.  
-- The message text returned is: This is message number 5.  
GO
```

Like you mentioned this is similar to the C# `string.Format("text {0}", "here")` amoungst other C# functions